# Django Weasyprint Timeout error for loading images in log

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, weasyprint

and I made a project that takes some pictures and converts them to pdf using weasyprint library. everything is alright in localhost but when I deployed it in python anywhere it generates the pdf but pictures that supposed to be in it dosent display and just the replace string of them is in the pdf please help me

Comment: Can you post some code of your project

Answer (score 1):

Weasyprint might not be able to load the pictures. Check that the [URLs you give can be accessed by Weasyprint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#urls). When in doubt, try using data URIs which don't require loading over the network.